# What is the difference between 'on' and 'against'?

Tags: prepositions, difference

[**Source**](http://www.phnompenhpost.com/national/arrests-made-acid-case)

> The parents of a brother-sister duo accused of a horrific acid attack **on** a pregnant woman and her 2-year-old daughter have been arrested.

In the sentence

> "acid attack **against** a pregnant woman"

what is the difference between 'on' and 'against'? Why was the preposition **on** preferred in the newspaper article?

Comment: That is not a sentence. It seems more like a title from a print publication (newspaper or magazine for example). Within the particular context on or against could be used interchangeably. Against is just a longer word and might make the title two lines instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

When **[attack](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/attack_1)** is a noun, the preposition **on** is preferred with locations, e.g.;

- attack **on** Pearl Harbour
- attack **on** Fort Sumter
- attack **on** (a) French church
- South Korea, US to simulate attack **on** nuclear facility ([CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/09/20/asia/south-korea-us-nuclear-drills/))

If ***[attack](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/attack_2)*** is used as verb, no preposition is necessary. All the examples below are taken from Google news

- ... attacked a homeless man
- ... attacked people at a shopping mall.
- seagull attacked customers
- ... attacked a humanitarian aid convoy

Compare the results for *attack on Israel* (blue), *attacked Israel* (red), *attack Israel* (green), and *attack against Israel* (yellow). All four are grammatical, but the first suggests that attacks on Israel are seen as acts of aggression aimed at a specific location rather than a nation. But it is a subjective point of view, so it would be interesting to hear from other native speakers.

[image]

In the example cited by the OP, the acid was thrown (at) or poured **on** the woman. The woman's body is considered a surface.  The preposition *on* is used to express physical **contact** with a surface.

> a horrific acid attack **on** a pregnant woman

The  main meaning of *against* is in "opposition to", in the following examples, *against* could be substituted with *on*.

- UN officials condemn attacks **against** (an) aid convoy
- his attacks **against** a Hispanic federal judge
- more attacks **against** Israeli soldiers and civilians
- Pakistan has initiated a string of attacks **against** India including major ...

However, between *attack somebody* and *attack against somebody*, the first preposition is usually preferred. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=attacked%20him%2C%20attack%20on%20him%2C%20attack%20against%20him&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cattacked%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cattack%20on%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cattack%20against%20him%3B%2Cc0) illustrates that ***[attacked him](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22attacked+him%22&tbm=bks)*** (blue line) is far more common than ***[attack against him](https://www.google.co.uk/#tbm=bks&q=%22attack+against+him%22)*** (green line)

[image]

Comment: @Lawrence can I ask you for feedback on this answer? Would you say that it is fairly accurate, or have I missed something? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it looks fairly accurate to me. I particularly like the *noun vs verb* observation you made. Your last point about the Ngram results may be difficult to interpret - *more common* doesn't always translate to *preferred*.

Comment: More on the answer. The feedback you were looking for was about the first Ngram, wasn't it? (NB: the link to that Ngram is missing.) I think "attack *in*" can be used to involve just the location and not the nation. *Against* clearly references the nation. *On* is harder to judge because of the possible physical interpretation, but I think it also references the nation.

Comment: @Lawrence yes, I was thinking whether I should add "in" into the mix, but the OP's question is between two prepositions. I thought it would be too much. I deliberately included only one Ngram link, if someone wants to check the first graph they can just change the words, the date span is the same, 1940-2000. *On* is indeed harder to judge, sometimes "an attack on"  can even be metaphysical.

Comment: Given your answer's approach, "in" definitely has a place in the answer, even if only as a passing comment. Also, when I read "Compare the results ... the first suggests ...", it looks like the results led to the suggestion. You're allowed two Ngram links - that's starting to make Ngram links sound like chocolate :) . Placing the link on the word "Compare" or "results", or even the phrase "Compare the results" wouldn't be out of place. If the noun *attack* is replaced with *war* to test the connotations of the sentences, I think the choice of in/at/on/against becomes clearer.

Comment: @Lawrence Food for thought, thank you. I like replacing "attack" with "war" suggestion. I will make a few modifications on my answer, maybe not immediately, but I will. I don't think adding a 2nd Ngram link is that important, I've posted the chart to save users the effort :)

Comment: The question is simply about meaning differences between two prepositions. Nothing about *attack* being a noun or verb is relevant. In any case, the term *preferred* as you use it is meaningless. Preferred by who? Preferred compared to what? Can a woman be a location? Where is the hat? It's on that woman. In addition, *Israel* can be a location, or an organization (nations are organizations), or the group of people who constitute it, or it's government, or a personified idea, etc. Not to be mean, but perhaps to help readers, This answer completely misses the mark.

Comment: And I completely disagree that it misses the mark.